# How to open setting->Privacy of iPhone in Cordova PhoneGap Application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

We are building Cordova PhoneGap application and using location service. 

Like in iOS Native app If Location service is disabled, the Cordova app should show popup that will redirect to setting->privacy page. So that user can enable location service.

Solution I am using:
To resolve this issue I have installed [Cordova Open Native Settings](https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings) plugin, that has provided list of settings(like Bluetooth, Location, Security.. etc.) that can be opened.
ALONG WITH TOW METHODS
FOR Android
    cordova.plugins.settings.openSetting("privacy", function(){ },function(){ });

AND FOR iOS
    cordova.plugins.settings.open(function(){},function(error){});

It works properly for Android but Not for iOS

**The issue with iOS is that it is opening Settings->MyAppSettingpage**
[image: Actually opening this my app setting.I don't need this one.]The above one is not require for me.
[image: This is expected for me.]
This is expected for me

**Please help me to do this using Cordova Phone gap.**
Thank's

Answer (score 3):

Try the following plugin (it is based on the plugin you are currently using). iOS 9 now supporting opening specific preference.

https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings

Comment: Nice update! I think the older one has been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open general settings only, you cant directly open location settings in ios.

try `cordova.plugins.settings.open(settingsSuccess,settingsFail);` to open general settings

Comment: Hey Hi, I have already tried this one. As I said above, it shows app settings and does not shows General Setting.

Comment: it's not working for me,  when i tried with ionic view.

Comment: @roshini : I believe it wont work with ionic view. Ionic view doesnt have setting page, isnt it?